# MySQL memory space

Tags: mysql, truncate

While using the DELETE and TRUNCATE commands in MySQL is the memory space released in the process?
Say if my table occupies 100KB and I DELETE all the rows, how much memory space is released?
And if I TRUNCATE the table, how much space is released if any?

Once I DELETE or TRUNCATE all the rows present in the 100KB table, what happens to the 100KB in each case?

Answer (score 2):

No memory is released as part of a `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` operation. In fact, memory might be consumed if buffers are used. It's usually irrelevant, though, since this will be re-used for other purposes when necessary.

Disk space *may* be released depending on what storage engine you're using and how it's configured. By default InnoDB allocates more and more storage on disk but never releases it, so you're stuck with the maximum allocation, the high-water mark. Freeing it up doesn't give you any disk space, but it does give you more space for MySQL to store data. It has just been reserved.

Comment: If I don't get more memory space then what is the use of DELETing or TRUNCATing the 100KB table? I might as well let the table exist even if it is of no use to me. I apologize if my doubts are really basic. I have never understood how these functions work out in the memory.